# LM test in VAR models

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression

One very important task, after estimating  VAR(p) model, is to test the residuals for autocorrelation. One possible test is the LM test. My question is the following: How to chose the number of lags in the LM test? Since I estimated a VAR(p) model, should I also look for autocorrelation in the first p lags only?